# Using Javascript RegExp to replace each match with an iterating number

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, iterator

I want to replace empty lines in my string with an iterating number

e.g.
replace

String:

```
"My first line

My second line

My third line"
```

with

```
"
1

My first line

2

My second line

3

My third line"
```

I can match and replace these lines using

```
var newstring = TestVar.replace (/(^|\n\n)/g, "\nhello\n");
```

However I'm struggling to add a function that will add an iterating number to each one.

Can you help?

TIA,

Gids

Comment: Please indent your code blocks with four spaces at the start of each line.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, will make sure I do this in future

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can do that in javascript. You just need to pass a function as a second argument to `replace`.

```
var i = 0;
var newstring = TestVar.replace(/(^|\n\n)/g, function() { return '\n' + (++i) + '\n'; });
```

function actually get a lot of parameters based on which you can decide what value you want to replace with but we don't need any of them for this task.

However, it is good to know about them, MDC has a great [documentation on the topic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#section_6)

Comment: Great, many thanks for the super-speedy and helpful response.

Comment: I thought this wouldn't work in IE 6 but in fact it does. Turns out IE 5 was the last version that didn't support a function as the second parameter in String.replace.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version without using a regular expression. You can use the `split()` method of `String`, though frankly I'd use the neater regular expression version.

```
var testVar = "My first line\n\nMy second line\n\nMy third line";
var lines = testVar.split("\n\n"), newStringParts = [];
for (var i = 0, len = lines.length; i < len; ++i) {
    newStringParts.push(i + 1);
    newStringParts.push(lines[i]);
}
alert( newStringParts.join("\n") );
```

Comment: It's always a good idea to look at the non-regexp alternatives

Answer (score 0):

To replace image paths with just names in html I did sth  like this

```
html='hello <img src="../../../../yahoo/images/icons/common/image_one.png">a<img \
src="add.png"> xyz <table><tbody><tr><td>He<img src="document_add.png">loo<img\
src="document_add.png"></td></tr></tbody></table><img src="CD_delete.png"><img src="check.png">'


html.replace(/src="(.*?)"/ig, function($1){return 'src="'+$1.match(/([^\/\\]+)\.(\w+)/)[0]+'"'  });
```

output will be

```
   "hello <img src="image_one.png">a<img src="src="add.png"> xyz <table><tbody><tr><td>He<img src="src="document_add.png">loo<img src="src="document_add.png"></td></tr></tbody></table><img src="src="CD_delete.png"><img src="src="check.png">"
```